# How to set a null value or equivalent to a field?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component state:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
}

interface CompState{
    //...fields ...
    person?: Person;
}

 render() {
     if(this.state.person){
       const comp = <div>{this.person.name + this.person.surname}</div>
     }

     ...
 }
```

In one of my handlers I'd like to "blank" the rendered component, so I would simply do this:

```
newState.person = null; //Type 'null' is not assignable to type Person | undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? It's not possible to re-set a variable to null in typescript?

Comment: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type Person | undefined`: so you can assign a Person, or undefined, but not null. Unless of course the type of the field is `Person | null`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

Comment: is "undefined" equivalent to "null" to achieve what I want? I never liked undefined myself as it is misleading..

Comment: Yes, it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two are equivalent in typescript:

```
person?: Person;
person: Person | undefined;
```

So if you want to 'unset' a value, you have to assign `undefined`.
Otherwise if you really want to use `null`, you can still do

```
person: Person | null;
```

Comment: A pedantic comment: optional property is not identical with property that may be undefined. `{ a: 4 }` is assignable to type `{ a: number, b?: number }` but not to type `{ a: number, b: number | undefined }`. For the latter, you'd have to actually list the `b` property and set it to `undefined`.